# Intl-tel-input: Make Country list dropdown width match the input field width

Tags: css, intl-tel-input

Can anyone help me how can I make the country list dropdown to always match the input field width?

[image]

Setting country list dropdown to 100% do not work. It should have 100% width of its grandparent. But, not sure how to achieve that.

It can be achieved by javascScript, but I need to do it using CSS only.
The width of the dropdown and the input field should be same when input field width changes.

Here is the online jsfiddle demo url:
http://jsfiddle.net/5num12gh/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="tel" id="phone">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#phone").intlTelInput();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you make a code example with this plugin which we can edit ? otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: @MihaiT Please check. I have added the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Check answer below. let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks, Working fine. Accepted the answer. Will definitely be helpful for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the position of the flagContainer to something other than absolute/relative so the dropdown doesn't position relative to it but to the div with the class `.intl-tel-input` which has the width of the input ( the only non absolute element inside it )

And then with some CSS position the dropdown and the flag accordingly.

Maybe there are other solutions like changing the `dropdownContainer` element as stated in the [DOCs](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) but not sure about that.

Check below snippet or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6a97vdLw/2/)

```js
$("#phone").intlTelInput();
```

```css
.iti-flag {
  background-image: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/10.0.2/img/flags.png");
}

body .intl-tel-input .flag-container {
  position: static;

}

body .intl-tel-input .selected-flag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 100%;
}

body .intl-tel-input .country-list {
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/10.0.2/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/10.0.2/js/utils.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/10.0.2/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="tel" id="phone">
```

Answer (score -1):

1. First change the order of `iti__flag-container` to:
   [image]

2. add `top: 17px` css property to `iti__selected-flag` class
3. remove `white-space` css property from `iti__country-list`

**Bingo your drop-down will be same width of parent**

Comment: The input textbox and dropdown html code is generated at runtime. I don't have control over the template, so I can't change the order of it without using javascript.

Comment: Please check jsfiddle demo link for more clarity